# location of kernel source code directory in centos 7

Tags: linux, centos-7, linux-kernel, make

I wanted to enable a specific feature in centos 7 kernel. What is the exact location of kernel directory in centos 7.4, so that I can lauch this command successfully inside the kernel source code directory:

```
# make menuconfig
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should read this documentation: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I think I don't need to build a custom kernel after reading the docs. Correct me if I am wrong: I need to search a specific kernel version which already has intended features enabled? That said, do you have any idea, which kernel version  has all IOMMU features enabled?

Comment: `make menuconfig` is used for one thing and one thing only, preparing for the creation of a custom kernel. If all you want is a list of the config settings, see /boot/config*. To obtain and locate kernel sources, see https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source.

Comment: CentOS7 source code https://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/os/Source/SPackages/